# Selecting rows with same id if all values of a column are different than some string

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an sql query, but I am new on this field, I need help. I have three tables and I have done 2 inner joins with the following query:

```
select a1.SYS_ID, a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS, b1.SYS_ID
     , b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID
     , b1.U_STATUS, c1.SYS_ID, c1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID, c1.U_STATUS
  from NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL a1 INNER JOIN NOCCIA_AUTOMATION_CONTROL b1
    on a1.SYS_ID=b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID 
 INNER JOIN NOCCIA_MANUAL_EX_CONTROL c1
    on b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID=c1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID
 where ( ( a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS='In Automation'
        OR a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS='Alarms Cleared' ) )
```

The result is the following:

[image]

SYS_ID is the primary key of the 1st table while U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYS_ID and U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYS_ID1 are the foreign keys of 2nd and 3rd tables. However, what I truly want is to select only the SYS_ID's for which all rows U_STATUS and U_STATUS_1 are different than a string s for that SYS_ID.

Comment: `are different than a string s for that SYS_ID` could you elaborate on this? Is `s` an arbitrary string?

Comment: Not arbitrary, different than "In Automation"

Comment: So `s` is the same as `u_journey_status`?

Comment: u_journey_status may have different values. String s is a constant string "In Automation"

Comment: In your query output all the sys_id have one for "In Automation" in U_STATUS. If you dont want "In Automation" then none of the rows will return correct?

Comment: Yeah, the table I posted is partial, but correct. I will try to explain better. As you can see from the table above, we have different rows with the same SYS_ID. For exaple, the table has two rows for SYS_ID=110 and four rows with SYS_ID=169. The query should check for each SYS_ID, that there is no rows with a U_STATUS equal to "In Automation", which means that, if one of the rows for the same SYS_ID has U_STATUS "In Automation", than this SYS_ID should not be in my output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a SELECT ... MINUS SELECT ... MINUS SELECT ...
The result sets of the 2nd, 3rd SELECT will be removed from the first result set.

Comment: I think `MINUS` is a bit of overkill here.

Comment: For performance it may perform better if you obtain first the set of primary keys using SELECT id ... MINUS SELECT id,  and then join with the  select * by id.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question and the comments, then all you need to is add one condition:

```
select a1.SYS_ID, a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS, b1.SYS_ID
     , b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID
     , b1.U_STATUS, c1.SYS_ID, c1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID, c1.U_STATUS
  from NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL a1 INNER JOIN NOCCIA_AUTOMATION_CONTROL b1
    on a1.SYS_ID=b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID 
 INNER JOIN NOCCIA_MANUAL_EX_CONTROL c1
    on b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID=c1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID
 where ( a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS='In Automation'
      OR a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS='Alarms Cleared' )
   AND 'In Automation' NOT IN ( b1.U_STATUS, c1.U_STATUS );
```

Comment: It is not enough. This only removes the rows in which b1.U_STATUS or c1.U_STATUS are equal to 'In Automation'. For a given SYS_ID, I want to check all rows for that SYS_ID and check if b1.U_STATUS and c1.U_STATUS are different than 'In Automation'. In the example above, I do not want for example SYS_ID 110 because one of its rows has a U_STATUS equals to 'In automation'. I just want a SYS_ID if all U_STATUS values related to that SYS_ID are different than  'In automation'

Comment: `For a given SYS_ID, I want to check all rows for that SYS_ID and check if b1.U_STATUS and c1.U_STATUS are different than 'In Automation'. ` I don't understand what this means, sorry. Maybe you could supply the data you're hoping to get.

Comment: Thank yor for trying to help. I will try to explain better. As you can see from the table above, we have different rows with the same SYS_ID. For exaple, the table has two rows for SYS_ID=110 and four rows with SYS_ID=169. The query should check for each SYS_ID, that there is no row with a U_STATUS equal to "In Automation", which means that, if one of the rows for the same SYS_ID has U_STATUS "In Automation", than this SYS_ID should not be in my output.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic version of `count()`. Table `data` is your query. For each entry `count()` scans rows with same `sys_id` due to `partition` usage. 
`Case when` clause checks if statuses are same. This way for each row we scan whole group. Outer query removes groups where at least one entry contains same statuses.

Here I simulated sample data, where only sys_id 115 meets criteria:

```
with data(a_sys_id, a_status, b_sys_id, b_status, c_sys_id, c_status) as (
    select 110, 'Auto',   4, 'Closed',  4, 'Closed' from dual union all
    select 110, 'Auto', 101, 'Auto',    4, 'Closed' from dual union all
    select 115, 'Auto',  17, 'Closed', 21, 'Open'   from dual union all
    select 115, 'Auto',  21, 'Open',   21, 'Open'   from dual union all
    select 169, 'Auto',  32, 'Closed', 33, 'Closed' from dual union all
    select 169, 'Auto',  33, 'Open',   33, 'Open'   from dual union all
    select 169, 'Auto',  44, 'Open',   33, 'Auto'   from dual union all
    select 169, 'Auto',  47, 'Open',   33, 'Closed' from dual)
select a_sys_id, a_status, b_sys_id, b_status, c_sys_id, c_status
  from (
    select a_sys_id, a_status, b_sys_id, b_status, c_sys_id, c_status, 
           count(case when a_status = b_status or a_status = c_status then 1 end) 
               over (partition by a_sys_id) as cnt
      from data)
  where cnt = 0
```

[**Count()** documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm) (look at analytic example), [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/973) and result:

```
  A_SYS_ID A_STATUS   B_SYS_ID B_STATUS   C_SYS_ID C_STATUS
---------- -------- ---------- -------- ---------- --------
       115 Auto             17 Closed           21 Open
       115 Auto             21 Open             21 Open
```